# Tire pressure monitoring system (TPMS) valve broken

Tags: jeep, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

The tire inflating valve was broken in the middle, Do I have to replace the whole TPMS part or just have to replace the valve, since I do not think my tire pressure sensor has problem. 
My car is a Jeep Grand Cherokee.

Thanks.

Da

Comment: What year of Grand Cherokee are we talking about?

Comment: It's a 2007 laredo 3.7L V6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the part you are trying to replace:

[image]

You can have it replaced. The cost of the part is under $5 from rockauto.com (I'm sure it's available at other places as well). It's called a TPMS Service Kit ([Schreader part #:34000](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=4496046&cc=1433828)).

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot @Paulster2, that's the answer I need so bad. You're awsome!

Comment: @DaleWang ... please select this as the correct answer if you deem it so.

Comment: Another note, just found out this discussion here at the jeep forum http://www.jeepforum.com/forum/f67/valve-stem-broke-mandatory-replace-tpms-sensor-1188898/, the OEM TPMS from jeep may not be replaced as two pieces (valve stem and sensor seperately) but should replace the whole sensor.

Comment: @DaleWang ... I think you need to reread the discussion. You can replace just the valve stem. Not only are there about 30 "kits" on rockauto.com, but in several of the posts in that discussion, they said the dealership replaced just the valve stems on these kits without issue. They also said you can get a band which will allow you to strap the sensor itself to the inside of the rim and put rubber valve cores in their place.